# JQuery function .load not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the next code. What am trying to do is when i refresh or open the page, to add the class intro. But my main problem is in the part :

```
$("body").load(function(){
```

I want when the page is opened, then to add the class `.intro`. Instead of body, i have also tried html, and still doesn't work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("body").load(function(){
          $("p").addClass("intro");
        });
      });
    </script>
    <style>
      .intro {
        background-color:green;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <img src="https://k32.kn3.net/taringa/1/9/3/9/4/7/32/johnny_te_toco/330x330_248.gif" width="304" height="236">

    <p><b>Note:</b> Depending on the browser, the load event may not trigger if the image is cached.</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `$( window ).load(function() {` or `$( document ).ready(function() {`

Comment: If you use `$element.on('load')` is not ambiguous. If you use `$element.load()` is ambiguous because `load()` method is an AJAX task, not an event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).load(function(){
         $("p").addClass("intro");
    });
});
```

Load event attached to the `window`. If that is what you meant? Load on a DOM element like that doesn't make much sense.

Whilst this should work, you could pull it out of your `ready()` event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Nothing to see here...
});

$(window).load(function(){
    $("p").addClass("intro");
});
```

This waits for the load of the window, but if you just want to add the class as soon as possible when the DOM is ready, well, you won't need the `load()` at all:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").addClass("intro");
});
```

**Bonus**: You should use `on()` to attach all events going forward.

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
    $("p").addClass("intro");
});
```

`on()` is the preferred method for events in *future* jQuery versions, as older methods are deprecated.

All the best.

Comment: Is better to suggest to don't use `.load()` method for events, because the ambiguity. `load()` method uses to make an AJAX call.

Comment: You are genius dude! Thanks a lot

Comment: `$(window).load()` is perfectly valid shortcut for `$(window).on('load'`. Says should use `on()` but no reason given.

Answer (score 3):

You should not use **[`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)** for this purpose.

> **load() function description :** Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.

You need just ready function to achieve that :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("p").addClass("intro");
});

//OR

jQuery(function($){
     $("p").addClass("intro");
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's nice to show the shorthand / "no-conflict" version as well: `jQuery(function($) {  /* ... do stuff, $ is safe in here */})`

Answer (score 0):

Put your code inside `$(document).ready` callback.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("p").addClass("intro");
});
</script>
<style>
.intro {
background-color:green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<img src="https://k32.kn3.net/taringa/1/9/3/9/4/7/32/johnny_te_toco/330x330_248.gif" width="304" height="236">

<p><b>Note:</b> Depending on the browser, the load event may not trigger if the image is cached.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For reference, see [Document Ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
         $("p").addClass("intro");
});
```

Comment: I like this answer better due `.on()` event method.